# iisnode.yml disappears during deployment

Tags: azure-web-app-service, iisnode, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using VSTS's Deploy Azure App Service task to deploy a node.js app to an Azure App Service Web App, supplying a custom `iisnode.yml`, `web.config`, and `deploy.cmd`.

My VSTS build artifacts looks fine through the explorer:

```
site
  config
  dist
  public
  .deployment
  deploy.cmd
  iisnode.yml
  package.json
  server.js
  web.config
  yarn.lock
```

The task has checkedmarked:

```
Publish using Web Deploy
Remove additional files at destination
```

The task's `Deploy Azure App Service.log` shows (it says Updating instead of Adding for `iisnode.yml` because I manually added one before this deploy).

```
...
2017-05-07T05:51:51.4939189Z Info: Updating file (MyRepo\iisnode.yml).
2017-05-07T05:51:51.4939189Z Info: Updating file (MyRepo\package.json).
...
```

And the `deploy.cmd` is pretty much just using `yarn` instead of `npm` from the scripts you can generate with the azure cli.

However, in the Azure debug console, it does not list `iisnode.yml`:

```
PS D:\home\site\wwwroot> ls


    Directory: D:\home\site\wwwroot


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
d----          5/5/2017   5:27 PM            config                            
d----          5/5/2017   5:27 PM            dist                              
d----          5/7/2017   7:07 AM            node_modules                      
d----          5/5/2017   5:27 PM            public                            
-a---          5/7/2017   6:43 AM         32 .deployment                       
-a---          5/7/2017   6:43 AM       3657 deploy.cmd                        
-a---          5/7/2017   6:43 AM       4509 package.json                      
-a---          5/7/2017   6:43 AM        148 server.js                         
-a---          5/7/2017   6:43 AM       2556 web.config                        
-a---          5/7/2017   6:43 AM     269807 yarn.lock
```

This causes the node process with run without the desired settings. What is removing `iisnode.yml`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Can you reproduce this issue with a new build/release definition? Provide the detail steps here. On the other hand, try to go to https://[your site].scm.azurewebsites.net >Debug Console> CMD, then check files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around I did was either put all the settings in `web.config` or just the line:

```
<iisnode configOverrides="iisnodeoverride.yml"/>
```

It seems changing from the default name made it stick.